# Arangoimp sporadically throws error "expecting array"

Tags: arangodb

when doing large json imports with arangoimp (using ArangoDB 2.4.0), sporadically a warning comes up:

```
2015-01-15T11:30:30Z [1268] WARNING at position 22213: invalid JSON type (expecting array)
```

1. The encording lines (here 22213) contents a proper json object. Is there a way to let arangoimp print for *which* attribute it expects an array?
2. As we are using schemeless documents, why is arangoimp insisting in getting an array anyway?
3. If this is a WARNING why is it reported as error at the end?

   created:          25416
   errors:           297
   total:            25713

The warned documents indeed where not imported.

Comment: This error will be reported if a JSON object is expected but none is provided. There are two ways to import JSON data: one is to put each document on a seperate line in the import file, and each file must be a JSON object. If not, then the above error will be reported. The second option is to create a proper JSON array/list with each array/list member being a JSON object containing the document data. If any of the array/list members is not a JSON object, then the above error will be produced, too. So is it possible that one of the imported elements is not a JSON object but a different type?

Comment: Will add some diagnostic output for this special case.

Comment: By the way, the warning does not refer to a specific attribute of an object/document, but it is raised when there is not object at all. For example, importing `{ "foo":"bar" }` would work (it is an object), but importing `"foo"` will not (it is no object). So it does not have to do anything with schemas.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helped again! Yes, it was not a problem of having an array or not. The json object in the line was not correct, in this case having an array like "arrayX": [ "a", "b", ] and my used json-prettyprinter was fault tolerant :-(
--> so, I got my personal concrete issue now, but I am quite sure that some further diagnostics output would be very helpful as while importing large amounts of objects it is really time consuming work to locate such errors :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just pushed a change that will improve diagnostics for these cases:
https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/commit/d7fa7e7a928d3d998fc8dddb372d07417c3d6646

It will produce better error messages, print the offending document and may also print the offending line in case of parse errors.
It also addresses the issue that warnings and errors are effectively the same when importing. So it now prints "warnings/errors" instead of just "errors".

Comment: By the way, the improved diagnostics will be included in 2.4.1.

Comment: Works very well now, and is really helpful to find mistakes!